# How can I make these linear equations have a solution?

Tags: matrices, determinant

There are 3 equations as follows.

> \begin{cases}&2x – y &= 5\\
>   &-x + 2y &= - 4\\
>   &3x - y &= -1\end{cases}

Using Gauss elimination, I worked out that the set of equations imply inconsistency, i.e there is no solution. I know to ensure if there is a unique solution, (where two or more equations intersect) the determinant must not be 0. However, I do not understand what I need to do in order to ensure the linear equations do produce a unique solution. Can I change the -1 value from the constant in the last equation to make a unique set? If so how, is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: For applying a determinant, we need a quadratic matrix. So just cancel one of the three equations, and you are done.

Comment: what do you mean by "make" the equations have a unique solution? A set of linear equations either has a unique solution, has no solution, or has infinitely many. Since you have two variables and three constraints, the case is usually the last one. An exception is when one of the equations contains the same information as the other two (e.g. is a linear combination). Then that equation can be removed as Dietrich suggests.

Comment: It sounds to me like he wants to know if there is a value of $k$ such that $\begin{cases}2x-y=5\\-x+2y=-4\\3x-y=k\end{cases}$ is consistent, to which the answer is of course yes.  Solve the system ignoring the last line to which you'll find that $x$ has to equal (...) and $y$ has to equal (...), and using those values for $x$ and $y$ you'll see that $3x-y$ has to equal $3(...)-(...)$ and this will be your value for $k$.

Comment: You can't make something that isn't true true by saying something else.  I can't make 2 + 2 = 5 by declaring that the second 2 is actually a 3.  But to come up with a different set of equations with a unique solution, since you have 3 equations and 2 unknowns simply pick one and throw it away.  That you got zero solutions the three are linearly independent and the remain 2 will have have a unique solution.  Just replace the third with any linear combination of the remaining two.

Comment: 1) replace 3x - y = 1 with #1 + #2 to get x + y = 1.  2)  replace 3x - y = 1 with 17 = 17 So 2x -y = 5; -x + 2y = -4; 17 = 17 will have unique solution.  3) Solve #1 and #2 to get  x = 2; y = -2.  So 3x - y = 7.  So replace 3x-y = -1 with 3x - y = 7. [Notice:  In *all* of these the third equation is superfluous and unnecessary.  Which is why I rather like the 17 =17 one.  If you are going to be useless you might as well be *really* useless.]

Comment: @JMoravitz yes this was what I was trying to say, however i don't understand your solution, can you explain it a bit further please

Comment: @aSoulja Solve the system $\begin{cases}2x-y=5\\-x+2y=-4\end{cases}$.  You learn something about the values of $x$ and $y$.  Now, using *those* values for $x$ and $y$ there is one and only one value for $3x-y$ that is consistent with those values, and that will be your value of $k$.

Comment: @SZN, two variables and three constraints usually means no solution.  More variables than constraints will more likely imply infinitely many solutions since you're more likely to have free variables in that case.

Comment: That s what I meant. Sorry if the wording was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solving the System $$2x-y=5$$ and $$-x+2y=-4$$ we get $$x=2,y=-1$$ plugging this in the third equation we obtain
$$3\cdot 2+1=7$$ therefore $k$ must be $7$